# Prove that, for a normal surface $\Sigma \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^3$ $(L \circ L)(u) - 2H(p) L(u) + K(p) u = 0$ for the Weingarten operator

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

As per the title:

I need help proving that $(L \circ L)(u) - 2H(p) L(u) + K(p) u = 0$, where $H(p)$ is the mean curvature and $K(p)$ is the Gauss curvature.

I realy have zero clue even on how to start.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Think about the fact that $L(u)$ is a linear map from a 2-dimensional vector space to itself and that $K(u)$ and $H(u)$ are related to the determinant and the trace of $L(u)$. Then recall what the characteristic polynomial of a $2\times 2$-matrix looks like and use the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

Comment: Sounds like a proof, rather than a hint! :)

Comment: It's not a proof by a long shot. $L(u)$ basically is given by the form

$L(u) = \begin{pmatrix} E & F \\ F & G \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} l & m \\ m & n  \end{pmatrix}$ and by simple algebra we can deduce that 
\begin{align}
K &= \det L\\
H &= \dfrac{1}{2} \mathrm{trace}L
\end{align}

Comment: My question is, what does $(L \circ L)(u)$ give? In other words, the shape operator of the shape operator is what?

Comment: This is an issue of linear algebra and does not depend on the form of the Weingarten map or anything like that. The Cayley-Hamiltion Theorem tells you that for any linear map on a two dimensional vector space the square can be computed as a linear combination of the original map and the identity and the coefficients are the trace and the determinant.